# Attach Galleries to Content Types

Tags: nodes, navigation, media

I am working with drupal 7 and I need to attach a gallery to the content type. I looked at the current solutions where I can create a Image content type and  create node references. I am looking for something where any user would be able to contribute images, multi-upload images at the same time, if possible can also add images from URL.

Also is it possible to do something where the user can just click on a "Add images" link and the user would be presented with a image upload screen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of approaches to this, the main difference being whether you use the [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module or Drupal 7 core's built in image field. The image field route I think will be simpler as you have to create your own view mode to have [custom image sizes](http://drupal.org/node/1026790) with [display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) and the 7.x-2.x version is still under heavy development. See the [related Media modules](http://groups.drupal.org/node/168009) for options. There are modules for multiple uploads and creating image galleries.

If you choose to use D7 core's image field you can add galleries to content types with the [Views Galleriffic](http://drupal.org/project/views_galleriffic) module.

Here are [Step by step instructions for D7](http://drupal.org/node/1578774).

You can also switch between styles.

Default

[image]

Thumbnails above

[image]

For multiple uploads you can try [Multiupload Imagefield Widget](http://drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget).

For a remote URL you can try [Filefield Sources](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources).

For an "Add image" button you can just create a link to the "/node/add/gallery" node or create a custom form.

Comment: When I say "Add Image", I want the user to be able to add images into the same gallery but not create a new gallery. Do you think thats possible ?

Comment: I think it would be simplest to just have a link that says "Add Image" that opens the node edit form for that gallery. That will take 5 minutes. You could spend a lot longer creating a custom form that only contains a imagefield upload form and attaches it to the current node. That would be a lot of work for little gain IMO.

Answer (score 0):

On the content type, using your image field settings you can enable the number of values greater than one.

For the file source you can use [FileField Sources](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) module.

And for the gallery display you can use [Gallery Formatter](http://drupal.org/project/galleryformatter)

Comment: I want to use a button which says "add images " and the user can be directed to the image upload field. Is there a way I can do this ?

Comment: How the images uploaded by users will be stored, which content types are you using ?
One image on One node ?
Multiple images on One node ?

Comment: multiple images in one node.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have found the answer already since your question is from May. If not, and for all those who are still looking, this is a great tutorial.

http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xnqe4c_creating-a-drupal-7-image-gallery-using-content-types-nodes_tech?start=0#.UOS4IRwujTN